# Error when trying to deploy React app created with Vite on Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, vite, vercel

When I try to deploy my app on Vercel, I get the following error:

src/App.tsx(5,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module './components/chat/ChatRoom' or its corresponding type declarations.
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 2

However, the import works in a local dev environment, and when I build the project locally it works as well.

[The component the error is about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvP3F.jpg)
[The import the error complains about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLMVB.jpg)

I'm really lost as to what could be the problem. The capitalisation looks fine to me, and everything works fine apart from the building on Vercel.

I've tried to rename the component and update the imports, but that doesn't do anything. I'm lost.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your Vercel deploy/build logs. Are you getting type errors in your IDE ? What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Next.js project? A quick and dirty solution if you just need to get it deployed would be to turn off typescript typechecking on deploy by setting in your `next.config`:

```
typescript: {
  ignoreBuildErrors: true,
},
```

Probably not what you're looking for tho...

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in ./tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    //this Line
    "strict": false,
    //this Line
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```